# how to load external js file in component with systemjs in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to load test.js in   statComponent  i try with System.import in the construncor but i get this error : Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/systemjs
    Error: XHR error……

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { System } from 'systemjs';

@Component({
template: `
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
 </div> 

`
})
export class StatComponent implements OnInit {
constructor() {
    System.import('./app/user/test.js').then(refToLoadedModule => {
        refToLoadedModule.someFunction();
    })
}

ngOnInit() { }
}
```

thi is sysytemjs.config.js

```
  /**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
 (function (global) {
 // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
'app': 'dist', // 'dist',
'@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
'ng2-toasty': 'node_modules/ng2-toasty/bundles/index.umd.js'

  };
 // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no 
extension
 var packages = {
'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
 };
 var ngPackageNames = [
'common',
'compiler',
'core',
'forms',
'http',
'platform-browser',
'platform-browser-dynamic',
 'router'
 ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
 function packIndex(pkgName) {
 packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 
 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
 function packUmd(pkgName) {
packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', 
defaultExtension: 'js' };
 }
 // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index 
files
 var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
// Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
 var config = {
map: map,
packages: packages
 };
 System.config(config);
 })(this);
```

Comment: js file not found. Check your path.

Comment: no ti think that the problem with system js "Cannot find name 'System"

Comment: What is http://localhost:3000/systemjs? Does the URL exist, try it in your browser.

Comment: no the problem with this : import { System } from 'systemjs' , he can't load it i update the qu with system.config .js di i have to do some changes in this file ?

Comment: You need to check in DevTools -> Network. What is the exact 404 request?